# why is "return true" in this function?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

in this specific example from Codeacademy, why do we need "return true"? 
does it do anything? (tried without it and got the same result.)

*(source: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/close-the-super-makert/0/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)*

```
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,
//insert the add method here    
    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.total += itemCost;
    },

    scan: function (item) {
        switch (item) { 
        case "eggs": 
            this.add(0.98); 
            break;

        case "milk": 
            this.add(1.23); 
            break;

        //Add other 2 items here
        case "magazine":
            this.add(4.99);
            break;

         case "chocolate":
            this.add(0.45);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

//Scan 2 eggs and 3 magazines
cashRegister.scan("eggs");
cashRegister.scan("eggs");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");

//Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```

Comment: Not in your example, since you are not doing anything with the return value.

Comment: This `return` statement has nothing to do with the `switch` and is in fact doing pretty much nothing.

Comment: any clue why "return true" is there if it's not doing anything?

Comment: @user3164317 *any clue why "return true" is there if it's not doing anything?* a misprint by CodeAcademy

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is ever done with the return value. You can omit that return and it will be semantically the same in the usage you've given.

If you needed to do something like:

```
if (!cashRegister.scan("eggs")) { 
    console.log("You forgot the eggs!"); 
}
```

returning truthy or falsey would make sense, assuming `scan()` could ever return falsey.

Answer (score 0):

This is not doing any thing, but we can use it instead of break statement.
In that case If we will return true from any case, this will be successful termination of the switch. And outside switch we can put return false, then it will be a failure temination, means no matching case found.

Comment: still confused. seems to work fine without the need to 'exit

Comment: Yeah, should work without return statement.